# "To serve" food at a party?

Tags: single-word-request

I am writing an invitation to a party in my home, and want to say something like "we will serve fruit" (or steak, etc.). The goal is to set some kind of expectations for how much food will be available. (It's a kid birthday party and I don't know the people I am inviting particularly well, though I see them frequently and wish them well.)

What verb for "serve" can I use? Everything around "dienen" feels very servicey-bureaucratic; everything around "anbieten" feels very Angebot-commercial. Am I smelling this right? Any suggestions for how to phrase this?

Comment: It simply is **servieren**. That answer may seem stupid but it's the core meaning of that word in German. An old-fashinoned alternative is **auftragen**. For beer, wine and other alkoholic drinks, it's **ausschenken**. But the informal way is to say and write *Es kommt X auf den Tisch.* and similar phrases. They are perfectly okay.

Comment: Weniger formal wäre "Es wird Kuchen und Obst geben." "Servieren" klingt für einen Kindergeburtstag schon reichlich feierlich - oder gibt es die Steaks/Früchte für die Eltern? "Wir werden den Kindern x und y anbieten" ist schon o.k. Für *dienen* sehe ich keine Chance: "Wir dienen uns Ihren Kindern mit schicken Häppchen an."

Comment: @Janka: Did you mean that "ausschenken" is also old-fashioned? It feels (to my very nonnative ear) so precious, like we are so pleased to be gifting out our drinks to you.

Comment: *Wir tragen X auf* is old-fashioned in any context. *Wir schenken X aus* is either very formal or old-fashioned, too.

Comment: @Janka: To me, *servieren* has the strong connotation of serving at the place where one eats. I wouldn't even use *servieren* in a posh restaurant referring to the food on a buffet, while *auftragen* may work. Thus, *servieren* seems unfitting for a birthday party that likely does without anything like a "waiter".

Comment: Look at dinner "invitations" of hotels. They write "Heute abend servieren wir ihnen X an Y". Posh restaurants tend not to have a buffet at all. Buffet is self-service, and that isn't compatible to being posh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjecture that *"servieren"* or *"anbieten"* don't work in such a context is correct.
For dishes that you prepare in advance, I would use the impersonal form *"es gibt ..."*, say, *"Es gibt Kuchen"* or *"Es gibt Bratwurst und Kartoffelsalat"*. For dishes that are prepared during the party, you can alternatively use *"wir* + present tense", say, *"Wir machen Crepes"* or *"Wir grillen"*.

Answer (score 6):

You could also say

> Es wird Obst und Kuchen geben

Or:

> Wir haben Obst und Kuchen (vorbereitet)

Or something along the lines of:

> Wir laden ein zum Kindergeburtstag mit Obst und Kuchen

Comment: Agreed, except that I find future tense in the first sentence non-idiomatic. "Es gibt Obst und Kuchen" sounds a lot more natural.

Comment: Imho only the fuuture tense is correct. I do agree though that colloquially the present tense would be accepted by most.

Comment: "Wenn Karolin Geburtstag hat, gibt es Kakao und Kuchen..."

Comment: @Burki  In linguistics, correctness is defined by actual usage, not by abstract rules, in particular not by abstract rules stemming from another language. There are languages where future tense is consistently used to describe future events – German is not one of them. In general, native German speakers do not use future tense if it is clear from the context that something happens in the future: *"Wann kommst Du?"* *"Im Juli habe ich Urlaub."* *"Dann bin ich leider auf Dienstreise."*

Comment: @Uwe Well... i am a native speaker. And the question states 'i am _writing_ an invitation', so spoken language is clearly not what is asked for here.

Comment: @Burk: aber auch im Schriftdeutschen wird das Futur nur selten verwendet.

Comment: @Uwe: Could one really write "Wir haben Obst und Kuchen vorbereitet" if the event is in the future? I am not a native speaker, but that certainly sounds past-y to me.

Comment: @Uwe. Cont'd: I think the future/present/perfect tense issue is actually what caused my initial dilemma. After floundering with "serve" (I considered "servieren" as well, but it felt too restaurant; comments on Ben's answer confirm this) I was trying to say something like "We'll have crepes" or "We'll make crepes" -- but the future tense ("Wir werden Krepps haben") felt preposterous and and the present ("Wir machen Krepps") inaccurate since we certainly won't be doing that during the party...

Comment: @Uwe. ...In fact, what's true is that we *will have made" them by the start time of the party -- but I don't think I have ever seen the future perfect in German outside of a grammar class. So my edited question is: since one often uses the present meaning the future, can one also use the perfect meaning the future perfect? In other words, could "Wir haben Kuchen gebacken / Obst vorbereitet" ever be used when the actual backening and vorbereitening is still to come?

Comment: @sibilant For dishes that you prepare in advance, I would use the impersonal form "es gibt ...", say, "Es gibt Kuchen" or "Es gibt Bratwurst und Kartoffelsalat". For dishes that are prepared during the party, "wir + present tense" is fine, say, "Wir machen Crepes" or "Wir grillen".

Comment: @Uwe: Feels like it's time for the coup de grace. Uwe, if you want to bother making your last comment an answer, I would accept it. (Otherwise, it seems I have to go with Ben.)

Comment: @sibilant ok, done.

Answer (score 4):

You could write

> Für Essen wird/ist gesorgt! (Steak, Obst ...)

or

> An Essen könnt/dürft ihr Folgendes erwarten: Steak, Obst ...

or

> Wer Appetit mitbringt, darf Folgendes erwarten: Steak, Obst ...

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your example: "we will serve fruit and steak".

You can use a direct translation, which is **servieren**:

> Wir servieren Obst und Steak.

or, to maintain the tense (which sounds a little bit less colloquial):

> Wir werden Obst und Steak servieren.

But this still sounds very formal. If you are not a restaurant (you are not, as you are inviting to a party at your home), I'd go with this:

> Es gibt Obst und Steak.

This reverse-translates to "There is fruit and steak", which is just fine in German. If you want to stress that there is plenty, you can add "genug" or even better "satt":

> Es gibt Obst und Steak satt.

I'd definitely attend if I read the last sentence. ;-)

Comment: In the context of a kid's birthday, "servieren" is way to formal. "servieren" is what the waiter does in a restaurant.

Comment: 1. Why the downvote? 2. No-one said anything about a kids party. Anyway, my answer reflects that "servieren" is very formal.

Comment: Totally agree that the downvotes (there were two) were excessive! But the fact that it's a kid bday party is mentioned in the question.

Comment: The question clearly states: "It's a kid birthday party". And in that context I consider "servieren" as a clear mistranslation. That's why I downvote your answer to signalize to other users that it is not a correct answer. Don't find that very excessive but rather in the logic of SE.